# Will the Windows Phone Stackexchange site be renamed after the release of Windows 10?

Tags: discussion

I realize this question can't be answered right now but I do think that this is something that will happen as with Windows 10, the "phone" suffix is disappearing from all official MS communication and therefore we should think about how to deal with this.

It seems that **Windows (10) Mobile** [might make a comeback](https://www.thurrott.com/mobile/windows-phone/2103/more-details-about-windows-10-mobile-emerge) to distiguish between the Desktop / Tablet OS and the one for phones and small tablets (<7.99").

So should / will this site be renamed (propably to Windows Mobile)? What are your thoughts?

[I've posted a similar question a while ago for reference.](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8649/what-will-the-next-windows-phone-version-be-called-officially)

Comment: Related: [Create just one SE for all Windows?](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/279/1401)

Comment: I rather prefer stick just with the mobile part. Desktop ans tablet things probably will fit better in Super User.

Comment: But, Windows 10 phones are computers? Just attach a screen...

Comment: This will only be possible with all new hardware though. And most questions regarding phones will likely not be relevant for desktop PCs.

Comment: http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-skus-are-revealed-microsoft-confirms-windows-10-mobile-smartphones

So, Windows 10 Mobile. Doesn't really sound much like Windows Phone.

Comment: I'd be in favor of renaming it to something like "Windows 10 Mobile". "Windows 10" brings it up to speed on the latest version (and it won't ever need changed again) and "Mobile" clarifies that it isn't for desktops or tablets.

Comment: I do not think Windows 10 will actually be the last version (number) ever.

Comment: At this time Microsoft is saying it is. Sadly we can't see into the future, so for the time the best we can do is believe them and name this site accordingly.

Comment: I like the name windowsmobile without any version number.

Comment: I think "Phones' Windows" is perfect.

Comment: @Thomas: Mac OS 10 has been the latest major version number of Mac OS for sixteen years so far.

Answer (score -1):

I think "Phones' Windows" is perfect name for site now. It will cover up all versions of windows phones and windows mobile (I am not sure if it is on-topic or not) as well as Windows 10 Mobile. It will not be affected by whether Windows 10 is actually the last version (number) or not. Moreover it will not harmful for windows phone as well.

Comment: No, this is too awkward. I suspect it may be grammatically incorrect. You could call it "Windows for Phones", or "Windows on Phones", instead.