# Site should be adopted into RetroComputing?

Tags: discussion

[This question is similar](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359/is-this-site-going-to-die) but some of the accepted answers points no longer hold true.

Some updates if you have been living under a rock.

1. [Windows Phone is dead](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/as-2018-is-windows-phone-dead#16688)
2. [Bill Gates has even switched to Android](https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/26/16365424/bill-gates-android-phone-switch).
3. [Windows Phone 7.5, 8 push notification support dropped](http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-phone-7-5-8-0-microsoft-just-killed-push-notification-services/)
4. (Update) Windows Phone's have been removed from Microsoft Store with staff suggesting no certainty on restocking.  There were only [2 windows mobile phones in the Microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/collections/mobilelist).
5. So it appears [Microsoft has given up on W10 Mobile](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-41551546) but it will still be maintained.

For those that use this on tablets which I have no idea what percentage that is I believe we should reconsider [renaming the site](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/will-the-windows-phone-stackexchange-site-be-renamed-after-the-release-of-window) to windowsmobile if the site isn't going to die.  [We could also reconsider supporting obsolete OS](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-windows-mobile-on-topic/18#18) although I doubt it will do anything.  The best option is adding support to retrocomputing.

Tags for search: dead end market share

Comment: See also my question on Retrocomputing Meta: [Would this site be open to adopting WindowsPhone in 5 years?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/942/would-this-site-be-open-to-adopting-windowsphone-in-5-years)

Answer (score 8):

To address your updates:

1. Doesn't really affect existing users of Windows phones. If anything, it's another topic to ask questions about.
2. Completely irrelevant, Bill Gates is not the "face" of W10M (nor of Microsoft, for that matter).
3. To be expected. Support for WP8 ended 2 years ago, for WP7 even earlier.
4. See #1.
5. See #1.

So I don't think all that much has changed since that question you linked to. There's no need for the site to die unless traffic drops below whatever threshold the Stack Exchange staff deem minimum. As for the name, while I agree that "Windows Phone" is not the best choice, it does not seem to deter people from posting questions about Windows 10 Mobile, so why bother changing it?

Comment: As you stated [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/16686#16688) "Yes, Windows Phone is dead."   You seem to be the highest rep user on the site(not that that guarantees anything) so I appreciate you responding.  According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207404) "We typically avoid renaming sites once they've gotten out of Area 51 - and especially if they've graduated and received a custom site design — and that continues to be true. "  I would recommend you considering renaming the site under what I have read prior to this site coming out of beta(if it appears it will).

Comment: I don't think this site graduating from beta is something we need to worry about in the near future. Also, renaming the site is not really up to me.

Comment: So I have asked the same question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308700/rename-windowsphone-se-to-windowsmobile-se?noredirect=1#comment1005920_308700).  Would you consider asking the other mods if they do or don't support this?  I believe a change would start with the moderators supporting this.

Comment: So I have pinged them in one of their questions.  Kinda tacky but I believe is the best solution with out using flags.  If you could comment on the question above if you do or don't support that that would be great.

Comment: @William I'm not quite sure why you wanted to duplicate the discussion elsewhere, but I've left a comment there.

Comment: WhatsApp stops supporting even WP10 at the end of 2019, I think that will be the final nail in the coffin - for me at least.

Comment: The most recent [question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/how-to-windows-mobile-6-5fusion-launcher-connect-to-802-1x-wi-fi) and [answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/16931/about-blocked-incoming-calls-and-sms/17126#17126) were both posted around 2 months ago now; the sites page says: [0.0 questions/day](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday); Windows Phone questions are even [regarded as on-topic at RetroComputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/550/16097).  Sadly, it's not a good sign.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones FWIW, the comment at RetroComputing.SE seems to refer to Windows Mobile, not Windows Phone or Windows 10 Mobile, which are the main focus of this site. I see your point regarding Q&A activity, but as long as Stack Exchange is willing to host this site, I see no reason to forcibly shut it down.

Comment: @Indrek I can think of 1 main reason the question per day have dropped .2 and continues to drop even more.  https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone

Comment: @William That's not necessarily a reason to shut the site down. Even if it were, that's not something I or the other mods here can do.